# How can I make FindPartialView search inside my Area?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I register all Areas in `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
  AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
  //...
  RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

But in my `/Areas/Log/Controllers`, when I try to find a `PartialView`:

```
ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, "_LogInfo");
```

It fails, `viewResult.SearchedLocations` is:

```
"~/Views/Log/_LogInfo.aspx"
"~/Views/Log/_LogInfo.ascx"
"~/Views/Shared/_LogInfo.aspx"
"~/Views/Shared/_LogInfo.ascx"
"~/Views/Log/_LogInfo.cshtml"
"~/Views/Log/_LogInfo.vbhtml"
"~/Views/Shared/_LogInfo.cshtml"
"~/Views/Shared/_LogInfo.vbhtml"
```

And thus `viewResult.View` is `null`.

How can I make the `FindPartialView` search in my Area?

**Update**:
This is my custom view engine, which I have registered in `Global.asax`:

```
public class MyCustomViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
  public MyCustomViewEngine() : base()
  {
    AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = new[]
    {
      "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
      "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
    };

    PartialViewLocationFormats = new[]
    {
      "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
      "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
    };

  // and the others...
  }
}
```

But the `FindPartialView` doesn't use the `AreaPArtialViewLocationFormats`:

```
"~/Views/Log/_LogInfo.cshtml"
"~/Views/Shared/_LogInfo.cshtml"
```

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem, I have a central Ajax controller I use, in which I return different partial views from different folders/locations.

What you are going to have to do is create a new `ViewEngine` deriving from a `RazorViewEngine` (I'm assuming your using Razor) and explicitly include new locations in the constructor to search for the partials in.

Alternatively you can override the `FindPartialView` method. By default the `Shared` folder and the folder from the current controller context are used for the search.

Here is an [example](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/06/27/view-engine-with-dynamic-view-location.aspx) which shows you how to override specific properties within a custom `RazorViewEngine`.

**Update**

You should include the path of the partial in your PartialViewLocationFormats array like this:

```
public class MyViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
  public MyViewEngine() : base()
  {
    PartialViewLocationFormats = new string[]
     {
       "~/Area/{0}.cshtml"
       // .. Other areas ..
     };
  }
}
```

Likewise if you want to find a partial in a Controller inside the `Area` folder then you will have to add the standard partial view locations to the `AreaPartialViewLocationFormats` array. I have tested this and it is working for me.

Just remember to add the new `RazorViewEngine` to your `Global.asax.cs`, e.g.:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
  // .. Other initialization ..
  ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
  ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MyViewEngine());
}
```

Here is how you may use it in an exemplary controller called "Home":

```
// File resides within '/Controllers/Home'
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var pt = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, "Partial1");
  return View(pt);
}
```

I have stored the partial I'm looking for in the `/Area/Partial1.cshtml` path.

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate further? I have now a custom view engine, and have set the locations (see my update), but the FindPartialView doesn't use them. Any pointes?

Comment: If you are trying to find a partial view in the Area folder from your normal MVC locations, ie root views, then i think you will have to add the path (~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml) to your PartialViewLocationFormats array.

Comment: I am trying  (~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml),showing the path but viewresult return is null.

Comment: Another hint would be that the `PartialViewLocationFormats` should also contain a variant of **"~/Area/_{0}"**, it seems that the underscore isn't added per default, although the underscore-based formatting is even embraced by the new file wizard for a partial. That's the naming convention I've imposed in my project.